# display won't return after being turned off

Tags: windows-7, display, sleep

I have a custom build PC running Windows 7.  My problem started a few weeks ago.  The power settings are set to not go to sleep and the display to never turn off, but despite this, after a certain amount of time (not sure exactly), the displays will turn off.  The problem is that when I then try to wake the machine up (again, it wasn't actually sleeping), the backlights comes on, but displays are just all black.  Nothing I do gets the desktop back, so I have to reboot the computer.

Comment: `My problem started a few weeks ago` - Any major changes to your system lately, i.e. installed new hardware or software (Windows Update perhaps)? What's the make and model of the monitor? Can you replicate the problem, i.e. connecting it to a spare machine?

Comment: not that I'm aware of.  I suppose it is possible though.  I have noticed the machine also seems to boot somewhat slower.  even the splash screen stays up longer than it used to, which make me worry that it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: How old is the machine? What do you mean by backlights exactly? How are you certain that the machine isn't actually sleeping? Have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting the video cable from your PC whenever you encounter this problem? You'll need to try to recall what changes you've made to your system recently as that will help you immensely (perhaps the System Restore feature might be a good place to start to see whether a new software/update had been installed). Otherwise, as you said, it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: The machine is about 6 months old. Backlights refer to the monitor. It lights up and is clearly on, but is displaying a plain blagh screen.

Comment: Have you tried using a different video cable?